# select A where A < B in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

so using LINQ attempting to compare 2 values in the DB and select where the date is less than exactly a year today...so anything between 24/1/12 & 24/1/13 will be selected.

So i've got...

```
  var selectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Station
             join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
             where InvoiceDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

this is producing a list but its not correct.
I've been playing about with the add years but can't seem to get it..
Anyone have any ideas?
Thank You

---

EDIT:
Hey everyone thank you for the quick response...i actually made a slight mistake, I want to return the value which has an invoice date of greater than exactly a year today.....So anything dated <= 24/1/12 will be returned.  i have used ur suggestions to use...

DateTime OneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

```
    var selectedObject  =
        (from workstation in db.Work_Station
         join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
          where InvoiceDate <= OneYearAgo
         select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

This returns a number of invoices...some of which are before the 23/1/12 and some of which are after.

Iv tried changing to where CurrentInvoiceDate >= OneYearAgo, which should return any dated between now and one year ago, but nothing is returned...what am i doing wrong? please advise...thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query matches your textual explanation. But both don't match your sample data.

What you want is all data where the date is *greater than or equal* (not less than) a year ago:

```
var selectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Station
             join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
             where InvoiceDate >= DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

If it is possible that you have invoices with a date in the future, you also need to specify that the invoices should have a date *less than or equal* to today:

```
var selectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Station
             join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
             where InvoiceDate >= DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)
                && InvoiceDate <= DateTime.Today
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

BTW: You want to use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`.
Using DateTime.Now would not return invoices from the 24/1/12 that don't have a time or that have a time earlier than now.

Comment: Thats great thanks for the help please see my EDIT of original post

Comment: @John: Than use the first query in my answer. BTW: You seem to confuse greater than (`>`) and less than (`<`) all the time. Your edit again contains this confusion.

Comment: Ok thanks Daniel...Although if I want a date that is before the 24/1/12 shouldnt that be <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);(so anthing less than (before) that date) is returned...??

Comment: @John: Indeed, that is correct. And now I quote your edit: "invoice date of **greater than** exactly a year today.....So anything dated <= 24/1/12"

Answer (score 3):

Provide date range which you want invoices belong to:

```
  var beginDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
  var endDate = DateTime.Now;
  var selectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Station
             join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
             where invoice.InvoiceDate >= beginDate &&
                   invoice.InvoiceDate <= endDate
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thats great thanks for the help please see my EDIT of original post

Comment: @John I've edited answer to show that you are not filtering your sequence. You should use property of invoice or workstation entities for filtering

Answer (score 1):

The code will look like this...

```
var selectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Station
             join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
             where InvoiceDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) &&
                   InvoiceDate <= DateTime.Now
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thats great thanks for the help please see my EDIT of original post

Comment: See you have to provide two dates one is one year ago's date, so your invoice date must be greater than one year ago's date, not less than

Answer (score 1):

I would use some external temporal variables, to avoid DateTime operations inside the query (Sometimes C# DateTime and SQL DateTime2 do not get along).

```
DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timeToCompare = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0)); ;
var selectedObject = (from workstation in db.Work_Station
                      join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
                      where InvoiceDate > timeToCompare
                      select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

See if it helps (I have many queries done this way :)

EDIT: As stated below, hadn't noticed that the comparison has to be actually GREATER than one year ago.

Comment: Thats great thanks for the help please see my EDIT of original post ---Iv tried...DateTime OneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0)); ..but same result